# Answering your own questions on SO after Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

I know that there are many discussions about answering your own questions and Jeff Atwwod encourages people to do that [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Does this hold true post Documentation because instead of asking and answering it you can just post it as a fact on Documentation? Meaning if you had a bug or something that you wanted to inform the SO community about you couldn't post it unless it was in question answer form and now you can. So is that still considered the best practice and/or acceptable?

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, sure, why not? Heck, do both - write up a good example in Documentation, then reference it from your self-answer. That provides a question with context, and an example that can be referenced for other problems.

Play around with it; I suspect it'll take a bit of experimentation to find the sweet-spot here. I think an ideal answer is very specific to a question, while an ideal example is a bit more general... But no doubt this depends heavily on the topic.

One of the big failings of "self-answer" has traditionally been the difficulty in writing a good *question* once you already know the answer - Docs should help resolve that by eliminating the need for a question when you *just want to write up an example.*

Note that neither Q&A nor Docs are particularly suitable as bug-trackers, although it doesn't hurt to note errata in Docs when relevant. So while I wouldn't use either for *reporting* bugs, if you want to add a note to an example on Docs that'll save someone the time you just spent tracking down your bug, that seems like it'd be a good thing to do.